# Primes as sum of squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> If $p_{i}$ and $p_{j}$ are two primes of the form $4k+1$ , with $p_{j} > p_{i}$,
>   show that if $p_{j} \neq$ sum of two squares $p_{i}$ is also not equal to sum of two squares.

- It is well known that primes of the form $4k+1$ can be written as a sum of two squares. However, my task is to prove this using infinite descent. So my strategy was to assume contrary and take an arbitrary prime which is not the sum of two square (say $p_{j}$) and to prove that if $p_{j}$ is not a sum of two squares, $p_{i}$ is also not a sum of two squares. By this, I will arrive at the number $5$ in the end which **is** the sum of two squares and hence our assumption will become false.
- I took two cases, one was that $p_{j}$ is a sum of three squares and the other was that $p_{j}$ is a sum of four squares. In either case, my strategy was to derive a contradiction by putting $p_{i}$ a sum of two squares. Moreover, my case division exhausted all the cases since by the sum of squares theorem, a number can be either a square, sum of two squares, sum of three squares or sum of four squares, and a prime cannot be a square. However, I cannot think of a way to derive a contradiction from either case.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You pretty much need to use specific facts about sums of two squares.  Do you know any theorems about this?

Comment: @Erik Wong What kind of theorems are you talking about?

Comment: You'll need to know a theorem about which numbers can be written as a sum of two squares (or just which primes).  Unfortunately, the problem becomes kind of boring after that :).

Comment: I cannot really understand the problem. It is well known that every prime of the form $4k+1$ is the sum of two squares, you can find many proofs of this fact, even on MSE.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree it doesn't make a lot of sense.  I thought perhaps it was in the context of becoming familiar with induction in some proof textbook.  But also it bears some similarity to the proof of $4k+1$, if one got confused with the quantifiers (if $p$ is not a sum of two squares, then $\exists q<p$ which is not a sum of two squares).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, I know that every prime of the form $4k+1$ can be written as a sum of two squares, but my task was to prove this fact using infinite descent, that's why I have said that I have to show that if $p_{j}$ is not a sum of two squares, $p_{i}$ is also not a sum of two squares. By this, I will arrive at the number $5$ in the end which **is** the sum of two squares and hence our assumption will become false.

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, I know that every prime of the form $4k+1$ can be written as a sum of two squares, but my task was to prove this fact using infinite descent, that's why I have said that I have to show that if $p_{j}$ is not a sum of two squares, $p_{i}$ is also not a sum of two squares. By this, I will arrive at the number $5$ in the end which **is** the sum of two squares and hence our assumption will become false.

Comment: One can use infinite descent to prove that if a prime is $4k+1$ then it's a sum of two squares, but the descent is a little more complicated than showing that if $p$ is not such a sum then neither is the next prime lower down.

Comment: What Gerry said - just as induction doesn't always mean using $F(n-1)$ to derive $F(n)$ for some formula $F()$, infinite descent doesn't always mean 'the _next_ smaller thing'.  It just means 'if $p$ can't be written as a sum of two squares, then there is *some* prime $q$ with $q\lt p$ that can't be written as a sum of two squares'.

Comment: I would go as far as to say that infinite descent is rarely, if ever, used in the context of "next smaller thing".  The formulation is aimed at producing "some smaller thing" without regard to whether there is anything in between the two.

Comment: Your strategy is doomed to fail. After all, $p_j$ can *always* be written as sum of four squares, so this can hardly lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Trying to prove this in this way reminds me a neighbor who tried to get rid of the snow with a cigarette lighter even though he had a perfectly good, working snowblower.

Comment: There's a proof by descent at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares  See also http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2008/descent1.pdf

Comment: So, have you had a look at the links I gave?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I looked at them, but they didn't used descent the way I have tried.

Comment: That's because, as we have been trying to tell you, the way you have tried DOESN'T WORK. The way it's done in those links, the way Euler did it, uses descent, and it works. So I really don't know what you want.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, Mr. Hagen von Eitzen told me that **assuming $p_{j}$ as a sum of four squares doesn't work,** but maybe to show a contradiction requires something more than that. What fact convinces you that it can't be solved by using my method?

Comment: @RobertSoupe Mathematics isn't just about a bunch of tools that you can use wherever they fit right. It is a flow of logical ideas and deducing one fact from another. It is interlinked and interdependent. To say that this "tool" and "trick" will work for this problem and not for that problem undermines the spirit of the subject. Hence to say that an elementary affirmative descent method will not work for my problem is incorrect.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Moreover, even if we have found a solution to a problem using advanced methods, elementary methods allow us to attain deeper concept clarity, thorough understanding and opens doors to new realms in the subject.

Comment: You are trying, Samurai, to look at two entirely unrelated primes and say something about one, assuming something about the other. In the Euler proof, the prime $p$ and the smaller number $m$ are directly related to each other in a way that involves sums of squares, and that's what makes the proof work. Trying to relate two unrelated primes isn't going to work --- why should it?